# Post value of submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, serialization

I have a `<form>`:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <button type="submit" name="age" value="20">Age 20</button>
    <button type="submit" name="age" value="30">Age 30</button>
</form>
```

When I am handling submission of this `<form>` with ajax like this:

```
$('form').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type     : "POST",
        cache    : false,
        url      : $(this).attr('action'),
        data     : $(this).serialize(),
    });
});
```

it completely ignores `POST['age']`. Is this intended behaviour or am I doing something wrong?

I've also tried `<input type="submit" name="age" value="30" />` without luck.

Answer (score 0):

[As per the jQuery documentation for `.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)...

> Only "[successful controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2)" are serialized to the string. **No submit button value is serialized *since the form was not submitted using a button***.

In other words, the button value will not be part of the POST array when the form is submitted with `.ajax()`.  A regular "non-ajax" submit, however, WILL include the clicked button in the POST array.

A workaround would be to simply append the value of the button onto the serialized array...

```
$('button').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type     : "POST",
        cache    : false,
        url      : $(this).parent('form').attr('action'),
        data     : $(this).parent('form').serialize() + '&' + $(this).attr('name') + '=' + $(this).val(),
    });
});
```

Note that I'm using the `click` event of the `button`, rather than the `submit` event of the `form`, so that I can easily capture which button was used.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/ty7c5k9b/**